# Quick doubt about chinese theorem: Giving the wrong answer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

i was doing an exercise, where I ended up with this equation:

$p = 1 mod (5)$

$p = 1 mod (2)$

I was trying to use Chinese theorem to see what number p takes form, but it is giving a wrong answer:
$p = \sum a^{i}x^{i}M^{i}$

$a^{i} = x^{i} = 1$

$p = \sum M^{i}$

$ p = 5 + 2 = 7$
:q

Comment: When p has same remainder when divided by a and b, it means it has same remainder when divided by ab. So the number you are trying to find can have form $p=10 m +1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the procedure of CRT:

> Given positive integers $n_1, \dots, n_k>1$ which are coprime to each other，define $N=\prod_{i=1}^k n_i$ and $N_i=\frac{N}{n_i}$. Given integers $a_1, \dots, a_k$, then the following system of coresidual equations
> $$
> x\equiv a_1 \pmod{n_1}\\ x\equiv a_2 \pmod{n_2}\\ \vdots\\ x\equiv a_k\pmod{n_k}
> $$
> have one unique solution when $0\le x < N$.
> Since $\gcd(n_i, N_i)=1\quad \forall i\in\{1, 2, \dots, k\}$, from Bézout's identity, we have for each $i\in\{1, \dots, k\}$, there exists integer $M_i, m_i$ s.t.
> $$
> M_iN_i+m_in_i=1
> $$
> solve the equations above for $M_1, \dots, M_k$, then one special solution of this system of coresidual equation can be represented as:
> $$
> x_0=\sum_{i=1}^k a_i M_iN_i 
> $$
> And general solutions are
> $$
> x=Nq+x_0,q\in\mathbb Z
> $$

In your case, it seems that you have the wrong $x^i$.

What we are to solve is
$$\begin{cases}
2M_1+5m_1=1
\\
5M_2+2m_2=1\end{cases}
$$
Apply [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), we have
$$
\begin{cases}
 M_1=3,m_1=-1\\
 M_2=-1,m_2=3
\end{cases}
$$
Thus a special solution can be calculated:
$$
x_0=\sum a_iM_iN_i=1\times 3\times 2+1\times (-1)\times 5=1
$$
And all solutions are of the form
$$
x = Nq+x_0,q\in\mathbb Z
$$